# Postgres: Oracle_fdw: Import foreign schema does not support if not exists

Tags: postgresql, import, schema, oracle-fdw

When we use import foreign schema in oracle_fdw, there is no option for IF NOT EXISTS.
Due to which if we re-execute the import foreign schema command to import the newly added tables/view we get the error that relation already exists.

As we are not aware of the table/view which were not added in the previous execution it becomes difficult to specify them in LIMIT/EXCEPT clause

Is there any work around available to achieve the IF NOT EXISTS functionality

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do that, but you can first find the foreign tables that already exist in the target schema and list them in the `EXCEPT` clause of `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`.

To find all foreign tables in a schema:

```
SELECT relname
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'f'
  AND relnamespace = 'schemaname'::regnamespace;
```

Then

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA "XYZ"
EXCEPT (/* list from above */)
FROM SERVER oraserver
INTO schemaname;
```